# Error inserting into database - value cannot be null

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I have created a table in my database, called `AccountCoupon`, which is defined as so in `AccountCoupon.cs` in `DataModel.tt`:

```
public partial class AccountCoupon
{
    public string CouponID { get; set; }
    public int Days { get; set; }
}
```

I am then creating the ID randomly using a char array of available characters and a for loop, and then adding it to the database:

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Request["CouponDays"]))
    {
        int days = 0;
        int.TryParse(Request["CouponDays"], out days);
        if (days > 0)
        {
            string cID = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                cID += couponCharacters[rand.Next(couponCharacters.Count())];
            }

            db.AccountCoupons.Add(new AccountCoupon { CouponID = cID, Days = days });
            db.SaveChanges();

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View();
}
```

However, when I try to add it to the database, it is throwing an error saying that `CouponID` is NULL, and that the insert failed. Which to me isn't possible because I just assigned it a value.

Comment: The item at the index 'couponCharacters.Count()' does not exist and therefor is null.

Comment: You aren't getting a compile error?  From what you've posted `ID` looks like it would be outside the scope of your db call

Comment: @greenhorn the second Random.Next() argument is the exclusive upper limit, so random will never generate the value coupnCharacters.Count(), so it's valid like it has been posted.

Comment: `ID` is not null based on the edits to your question... is this all one method and contiguous code?  `empty string` is not `null` so even if the for loop changed nothing, you should not be the error about ID being null.

Comment: I debugged the code, but it's working perfectly for me (just added the `;` at the end of the line inside the loop and a few dummy characters in the `couponCharacters` array), so I can't find any problem with the (updated) code posted.

Comment: @LInsoDeTeh the specific error I get is: `System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException` - "Cannot insert the value NULL into column CouponID". I've debugged and the string `ID` has a value. Could be something in my DataModel, though I `StoreGeneratePattern` to None

Comment: Does `DataModel.tt` contain custom code? Has your model been modified, so that your `CouponId` property maybe does not map to the `CouponID` database column? Or ist it all default EF model?

Comment: @LInsoDeTeh it's all default. I made a new table in the existing model, generated the script, ran the script on the database, and started working with my code. The new table doesn't reference any of the other tables so it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: why don't you post the entirety of the method(s) involved with your object creation and context save?  What you've posted looks correct enough, I can only guess it's something else separate from what you've posted that is causing an issue.  Right now is seemingly like a "cannot reproduce" question.

Comment: @Kritner I added the entire function instead of snippets

Comment: @user3189142 so your db context is being instantiated from outside of this method, could something else be adding to the context that doesn't meet the column requirements?

Comment: @Kritner okay, apparently even though I set `StoreGeneratedPattern` to None, it went ahead and changed it back to Identity. Making it None again fixed my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was in the property `StoreGeneratedPattern` for the `CouponID` property of the table. It was default set to the value of `Identity`, which causes errors because a string cannot be generated automatically. Setting the value to `None` solved the issue:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a string instance named `ID` everytime inside the loop. So it only exists inside the loop. Try

```
string ID = string.Empty
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    ID += couponCharacters[random.Next(couponCharacters.Count())];

db.AccountCoupons.Add(new AccountCoupon { CouponID = ID, Days = iDays });
```

Comment: My bad, I actually have the string declaration outside the loop, I'll update my question